# Passing karma configuration object from gulpfile

Tags: gulp, karma-runner

I have a `karma.conf.js` file that exports a function that takes a `config` object and applies a bunch of configurations to that object.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
...
```

If I start karma from the command line like this: `karma start`, it runs correctly. Clearly the karma start function is inserting the required `config` object when it calls the function exported by `karma.conf.js`.

I am trying to start it with a gulp task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  var karma = require('karma').server;
  var karmaConf = require('./karma.conf.js')();
  karma.start(karmaConf, done);
});
```

This gives me an error because the `config` parameter is missing.

Two questions:

1. How can I get the karma config object to include as a parameter, and
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
  var Server = require('karma').Server;
  new Server({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, done).start();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this question is a little old, but I found it when I was about to post my own q/a to something similar. The main difference being that I'm not working with gulp, but am just using Karma's public API directly. I'm still stuck using [Karma v0.12](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/dev/public-api.html), but it doesn't look like the spec has changed in this regard. It still requires an ordinary object, and my config file exports a function, just like in the OP's situation.

The main problem with the sample in the question is it tries calling the config function without providing any arguments. That is probably what is throwing the error. In particular, the config function expects a single input `config`, and calls `config.set(actualConfigObject)`. What I did was write a function of my own that provides a minimally suitable object.

All that is needed is to ensure that what is passed in to the config function has a `set` function that in some way captures its first argument for later use. I actually ended up wrapping all that in a function that returns the argument for convenience:

```
function extractConfig(configFunction) {
    var last;
    var shell = {
        set: function (input) { last = input; }
    };
    configFunction(shell);
    return last;
}
```

Then I can call this with my required config file:

```
var config = extractConfig(require('./local-karma.conf.js'));
```

Which got my tests running. I have noticed that something is slightly off, since I override the logging level in my config, but the API seems to be using `config.LOG_DEBUG` regardless. But that's the only problem I've had so far. Though [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413377/how-to-override-karma-config-using-karma-public-api) seems to also be doing something similar, but with less successful results.